# Выбор рекламных сетей для admob

Tags: android, admob, реклама

В настройках баннера admob есть раздел - Медиация, там можно добавить новую рекламную сеть из списка предоставленных.

Чем отличаются эти рекламные сети? Как из них выбрать нужную если меня интересуют объявления из конкретной категории? Какими рекламными сетями пользуетесь Вы?

Также в настройках admob есть раздел - Разрешить/Блокировать. Там выбрать объявления с какими категориями будут отображаться а с какими нет. Но там можно заблокировать не более 50 категорий, что мало для меня.